# Creating new word-embeddings out of desired words from the vocab

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I have created word2vec for some text data using count vectorizer. Now I want to group certain words from the generated vocab (that denote common meaning/aspect) into new single word, and thus find the new word2vec representation.
How should I solve this problem ?

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = {'some_text': ('cat is red and fat', 'dog is blue hairy thin','horse is brown and tall')}
data = pd.DataFrame(A)

#       some_text
#    0  cat is red and fat
#    1  dog is blue hairy thin
#    2  horse is brown and tall

cv = CountVectorizer()
vec = cv.fit_transform(data.some_text)
df = pd.DataFrame(vec.toarray(), columns=cv.get_feature_names())

#       and  blue  brown  cat  dog  fat  hairy  horse  is  red  tall  thin
#    0    1     0      0    1    0    1      0      0   1    1     0     0
#    1    0     1      0    0    1    0      1      0   1    0     0     1
#    2    1     0      1    0    0    0      0      1   1    0     1     0
```

I want to group certain words from the bag-of-words into another word like this :

```
color = {'blue',' brown', 'red'}
body = {'fat', 'thin', 'tall'}
animal = {'cat',' dog', 'horse'}
```

I want the vocab to have the above words ( for example,  word 'animal' instead of 'cat' , 'dog'  or ' horse') and then get the word-counts. How should I proceed to get new desired word-embeddings?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows you using `CountVectorizer` to create vector representations of the 3 texts. It doesn't yet show any use of the word2vec algorithm. So you don't yet have any per-word word-vectors.

For what you've literally asked - to be able to replace the animals with the token `animal`, or the colors with the token `color`, it'd probably be better to use a pre-calculated reference lexical database, like say the popular '[WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/)', which actually describes such relationships. (Specifically, those more-general words that include multiple variant more-specific words are called 'hypernyms', and in WordNet, you can look up hypernyms of other words.)

If you actually do need word-vectors, instead, you could either try reusing someone else's trained word-vectors, if you think their training data is similar enough to yours that the word-vectors are suitable.

Or, you could train up your own word-vectors from your own training texts. But, you'd need far, far more text than those 3 short sentences: good sets of word-vectors require millions of words of realistic-usage, varied training data.

However, word-vectors don't easily work for the specific 'replace-a-word-with-its-hypernym' request you've made - as the relative similarities between word-vectors don't cleanly encode the 'more-general' (hypernym) or 'more-specific' (hyponym) kinds of relationships. (For example, 'animal', 'cat', 'dog', and 'horse' might all be close to each other, but it'd be hard to be sure 'animal' was the most general term, without using other outside knowledge.)